Why is it harder to determine the expectation of *a single qubit* in the ground state than determining full the ground state (energy) itself?
I learned recently upon watching a presentation by Sev Gharibian that after Kitaev's breakthrough showing that $5$-local Hamiltonian is QMA-complete, others such as I. Cirac, A. Ambainis, and (our very own) N. Schuch asked how hard it is to determine, not the full ground state $|\psi\rangle$, but rather the expectation of a single qudit in the ground state of a local Hamiltonian, no matter how entangled the state be.
Gharibian and Yirka followed up by showing that the problem is complete for (an odd?) class P$^\mathsf{QMA[log]}$, which likely fits between QMA and an even harder class PP. If I'm interpreting their results correctly, even determining the expectation of the first qubit of the ground state of a $k$-local Hamiltonian is likely harder than determining, or even writing down, the full ground state and its energy itself.
Contrast this with a counterpart classical problem, where I think that if we are given an oracle to know the expectation of a particular bit to maximize the number of satisfying clauses of a 3SAT instance (that is, how often it's 0 or 1 in all such instances), then we can recursively assign the other bits by fixing our queried bit to 0 if the expectation is less than 50% and 1 if it's greater. This recursion seems to suggest that the counterpart classical problem is no harder than the standard MAX-3SAT problem.
So why is it harder to learn the expectation of one single qubit in the ground state of a local Hamiltonian?
Does the recursion fail somehow?  Or am I totally off base?

This class is not that odd, as a function class (which makes much more sense conceptually, in the end you want to compute the energy etc., rather than asking decision questions about it), a log-number of QMA queries is precisely what is needed for a 1/poly accuracy.

As for the recursion argument -- I'm not sure whether your 50%-argument is sound, but there is a thing called "decision to search" (i.e., if you can have e.g. an NP-oracle, can you use it to find a proof = solution), which is known to work for NP and QCMA, but fails for QMA. Can try to dig out the paper (around 2009+epsilon, there was a poster at QIP in Santa Fe).
EDIT: Not what I had in mind, but they show that this is impossible for QMA relative to an oracle: https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.02999

Thanks - if one were to iterate Max-3SAT, asking what the expectation is for each bit is separately, and choosing, e.g., $(0,1,1,0,1)$ if the expectation for the first bit is 0.34%, for the second is 0.88%, the third is 0.76%S, etc., would that input necessarily have a maximum number of accepting clauses?

Also, as far as calling it "odd" I was thinking of Gharibian's characterization as he hinted it wasn't clearly well-motivated, but I guess I can strike that from my question if it's not appropriate.

I'm not even sure what "expectation for each bit" in the max-SAT case means. For a randomly drawn solution? Either way, these kind of reductions for randomized classes have some subtleties; not saying it doesn't work, but I don't see the necessity either -- in the specific case in question, just fix the bit you care about, get a new 3SAT, and ask for its value: This you can use to determine the admissible value of the bit in question. --- I'm not saying "odd" is inappropriate, but I think the log-queries are very natural in a very natural sense.

... and it is also very natural to design a protocol in this class, by using perturbation theory (i.e. the difference in ground state energy of $H$ and $H+O$).

Thanks. I guess I would consider a Max-3SAT instance with lots of assignments leading to the maximum # of accepting clauses, and ask the expectation of each bit over only those assignments. Perhaps I would call that a high amount of degeneracy in the quantum case. Also at the end of the presentation at around the 52-minute mark, Gharibian suggests that the issue is the that we don't know the ground-state energy itself. This I guess would be akin to not knowing what the Max-3SAT value actually is.
